# Why i can't auto run a JS function after ajax Retrieving function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#button1").click(function(){
 if(document.getElementById("hidValid").value == "Correct Username & Password"){
             parent.result.location.href="user.php";
            window.location.href="welcomeuser.php";
         }
      });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate_use_pass(username,password){
        var loginUserID = document.getElementById("loginUserID").value;

        var passUserID = document.getElementById("passUserID").value;

        if(loginUserID == ""){
            alert("Invalid Username/Password.");
        }else if(passUserID == ""){
            alert("Invalid Username/Password.");
        }
        if(loginUserID == "admin" && passUserID =="admin" ){
    parent.result.location.href="account.php";
    window.location.href="welcome.php";
        }else{
            var xmlhttp;
            /*if(username.length==0 || password.length==0){
                document.getElementById("validateText").value="Enter Username/Password";
        return;
    }*/
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("validateText").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("hidValid").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","validateUsePass.php?username="+username+"&password="+password ,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

}

The problem is that I can't seem to run a function after the "xmlhttp.send();".
because of this when I log in I need to press the button 2x to run the JS function.

what happens is that the first press of the button will retrieve the data from the PHP then second one will run the JS function.

Comment: place your additional function in here: `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`

Comment: As you are using jquery already, it would be a lot easier to use one of jquery's ajax functions as well; it would shrink your code in half and probably solve your problem at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'validateUsePass.php',
        data: {
            username:$('loginUserID').val(), 
            password:$('passUserID').val()
        },
        success : function(data){
            alert('success')
        },
        error  : function(data){
            alert('error')          
        }

    } );
```